# Show "ID" word in url in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<a href="@Url.Action("UpdateCase", "Receptionist", new { id = @Model[SrNo].Patient_ID })" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
```

In a href, I've pass id as parameter. so when I redirected to action I have following url

> http://localhost:17888/Receptionist/UpdateCase/12

But I want id word visible in url.

> http://localhost:17888/Receptionist/UpdateCase?id=12

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

If I change parameter name rather than id, it is working. only id is not visible in url

UpdateCase Action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateCase(Int64 id)
{

}
```

Comment: Try to add attribute   [Route("{action}/id={0}")] to action Receptionist

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action(Route("{Receptionist/UpdateCase}/id={0}"), @Model[SrNo].Patient_ID)" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a> it should be something like this?

Comment: No, it shoult be as an attribute on your action in controller

Comment: Can you show the controller action for `UpdateCase`?

Comment: @LarsKristensen - Does UpdateCase Action really matters for this? because as far as I understood, this is routing issue. isn't it?

Comment: @MegaTron- Can you write code here? I can not exactly find how to write it in attribute

Comment: @MegaTron- I tried that as per Joseph told. but when I tried that, nothing happened on button click. please check image:http://prnt.sc/dn0coz

Comment: I guess it's not the most important part, but it would be helpful to see if the controller action accepts the expected parameter(s). It will be difficult to try an reproduce the issue, if we don't know the implementation details (not the behaviour of the action, but at least the method signature).

Comment: @LarsKristensen- I added UpdateCase in edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solution is change your route config to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{param}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In that case you won't have a parameter with name `id` in the route table, so `Url.Action` can't use it and as a result you wil get expected url.

But be careful and check others actions

Comment: So we have change default parameter from id to param. it works!

Comment: yes, check if it is not break other case. Glad to have been of help

Comment: yes I will check it. I am at just start of my project, so I don't think so it would be problematic in future

Answer (score 0):

Question marks are added when the parameter is not specified in the URL, so removing the `{id}` from your route will force the question mark to be added in the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: When I remove id from route, redirection stops working and nothing to happen on button click.

Comment: How are you generating the link, can you add the code to your question?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "About", "Home", new { id = 5 }, null)` This works for me?

Comment: its at the first line of my question

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. This seems to work for me: `<a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home", new { id = 5 })" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>`

Comment: even when I hover button, browser stops showing redirection link on left corner.